# Error in Android Studio 3.0 beta 2

Tags: android

I am facing the error shown below after upgrading my App from Android Studio 2.3.3 to Studio 3.0 beta?
Is there anything I can do to solve this problem ?

```
Error:org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Comment: Fixed grammar and formatting

Comment: Heyy Thomas .. Sorry about grammer and formatting. Could you help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to latest beta gradle. Just clean project and resync. And your problem will be solved.

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

Comment: can u post build.gradle file from app and root directory?

Comment: Heyy My Problem Resolved once after remove below library
classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
and then gradle build successfully.